# Misplaced UIAccessibilityFrame for UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uiaccessibility

I'm dealing with a legacy project where all views are created programmatically (no xibs or storyboards). When trying to swipe through accessibility elements in a custom view, the UIButton accessibilityFrame seems to be in the wrong position. [image: Accessibility Inspector screenshot]

Voice over reads it correctly and the accessibility frame shows as `{{11, 54}, {43, 37}}` when debugging in console. The custom textview and button are:
`<UIPlaceHolderTextView: 0x10087f600; baseClass = UITextView; frame = (55 151; 240 85)>,
<AddEventButton: 0x1004954d0; baseClass = UIButton; frame = (11 54; 43 37)>`
Has anyone ever seen this issue that could point me in the right direction? I've tried creating UIAccessibilityElements without any luck.

UPDATE: After a lot more digging into the 2500+ lines of code in that file, I did find that the accessibilityFrame was manually being set (incorrectly) in a scrollview delegate method.